# Python : Fibonacci sequence using range(x,y,n)

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, fibonacci

I was interested in finding a way to make a variable that gets a value and store it in another variable then getting a new value.
A close practical example is the Fibonacci sequence.
I reasonably searched hard through available python code for this sequence.
There were tons, most often too cryptic for my basic grasp.

I came up with this one. Simple and should do the job :

```
a = 1  
b = 0  
print (b)
print(a)
for i in range(0,100):  
 c = b  
 b = a  
 a = c + b  
 print(a)
```

In the end, the loop should print the values passing through the variable a, as in :
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89

But that freakin i keeps going all the way to 100^10.
As in the final output for that code is :
0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377, ..., 573147844013817084101

Would someone explain what is happening ?

Comment: You are getting 100 values, the `for` you have will make the calculations 100 times

Comment: It's because the loop is doing exactly what you told it to do: print the first _i_ Fibonnaci numbers, with _i_ at most 100. For the record, the 100th Fibonnaci is 354224848179261915075.

Comment: Ok. I set the increment to 10, and that divided the number of values. But I, now, have more questions than before.

Comment: @Ashkat I get that the range is between 0 calculations and n number of calculations. I know now that I don't understand this function. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running through the lines

```
 c = b  
 b = a  
 a = c + b  
 print(a)
```

100 times. So you get the first 100 fibonacci numbers.

If you want to print fibonacci numbers up to 100, change the for loop to a while loop as such

```
while (a < 100):
     c = b  
     b = a  
     a = c + b  
     print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have used this iteration. The fist comments pointed me to adding an increment as :  in for i in range(0,100,10)

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer this kind of output as a list instead of printing everything in the loop. Here are the Fibonacci numbers less than 1000:

```
fib = [1,1]
i = 0
while i < 1000:
    fib.append(fib[-1]+fib[-2])
    i = fib[-1]
#we need to remove the last entry because the loop doesn't stop until the output exceeds 1000.
fib.remove(fib[-1])
print(fib)
```

It is more interesting to get the Fibonacci numbers up until a certain condition is met instead of an arbitrary numerical cutoff. For instance, the code below detects the first Fibonacci number after 1 that is a square using a while loop over list comprehensions:

```
#find the lowest square above 1 in the fibonacci sequence
squares_in_fib = []
squares = []
fib = [1,1]
i=0

while squares_in_fib == []:
    i = i+1
    squares = [x**2 for x in range(1,i)]
    fib.append(fib[-1]+fib[-2])
    squares_in_fib = [x for x in squares if x in fib and x > 1]
print(squares_in_fib)
```

As an aside, I think 144 is the only one!